# Identifying Gazebo objects with a GpuRaySensor

Tags: ros, gazebo, pointcloud, laserscan

I want to identify objects within a laser scan provided by Gazebo with the aim of obtaining point-wise ground truth data. Using the `gazebo::sensors::RaySensor`, I can assign a `<laser_retro>` value in as .sdf file such that each point that lies on the respective object gets the specified intensity value.
However, this is not possible for the `gazebo::sensors::GpuRaySensor` (see [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/26978/why-gpuraysensor-do-not-support-intensity-readings)).
The CPU ray sensor is too slow for my application.

Is there another way to distinguish elements in the point cloud?

Comment: As GPU lidars are basically 4 cameras stitched together, can't you just add a set of 4 RGB cameras with the same resolution and identify the objects by color? Or even better, directly use segmentation cameras?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly. Where can I find information on the lidar being stitched cameras? Also, I need depth information for each point/pixel rather than just a color. Does a camera provide these?

Comment: Depth or RGBD cameras can provide depth info :) You can find the multi-camera lidar implementation here: https://github.com/gazebosim/gazebo-classic/blob/gazebo11/gazebo/sensors/GpuRaySensor.cc#L198 and here: https://github.com/gazebosim/gazebo-classic/blob/gazebo11/gazebo/rendering/GpuLaser.cc#L608 . But if you're not a graphics guy, it might be kind of complicated to grasp.